# Link userscripts.org to careers profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Could we have an integration from careers with [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org), like we already have for github, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** It's live!

--

We just added the ability to add "other" projects to your profile, by going to the Open Source section and clicking on... "other". Give it a try and let us know what you think.

Comment: I still don't see it... or am I missing something?

Comment: @fretje Nope, you're not missing anything - we're waiting on something else before pushing it. Hang tight.

Comment: @fretje this is live now... thanks for bearing with us.